# Media player c# playing from network

Tags: c#, networking, location, media-player, windows-media-player

I´m trying to play a file located on network at address:

```
string filePath = @"\\192.168.xx.xx\folder\folder2\Audio\audio.wav";
```

and trying to play it in MediaPlayer.MediaPlayer player like this:

```
m_player = new MediaPlayer();
m_player.Stop();
m_player.Open(new Uri(path));
m_player.Play();
```

It doesn't return any exception, but it also does not play the sound.
When I copy the file on a local disk and try to play it, it works fine.

Any ideas where the problem could be?

Comment: What about if you open the file from windows explorer? Does it play properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some Google says, that you should try a relative Uri.

```
m_player = new MediaPlayer();
m_player.Stop();
m_player.Open(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));
m_player.Play();
```

Otherwise have a look at this [example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winappswithcsharp/thread/81ceffb9-2d8a-4902-8295-09a2706bd438), which opens a stream and sets the stream to the MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

The [SoundPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5bfdtza.aspx)  class can do this. It looks like all you have to do is set its Stream property to the stream, then call Play.